Jmeter if control start next thread
I would like to make a simple condition
Test plan -> thread group ->
Http Request 1
Http Request 2
If request 2 failed start next thread (from request 1 )
Http  Request 3
Http  Request 4......
How could I do that ?
If request 3 failed I don't care so for other request so I can't define any error start new thread at thread group.
Thanks

You can add a JSR223 PostProcessor to your test plan and use the following code in the Script area:
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD)
}

whenever any Sampler in the JSR223 PostProcessor's scope fails it will not continue and will start the next iteration of the thread instead
See Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article to learn what do these prev and ctx guys mean.

Thank... i tried it before and it wasn't work properly . I found a solution by adding Result Status Action Handler sampler - do the job correctly.  thanks again
